# 'com.android.support:support-v4' dependency issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to integrate react-native-beacons-manager to my react-native project on PhpStorm, so i installed the library using the command "yarn install react-native-beacons-manager" and then link it to my project using the command "react-native link react-native-beacons-manager". But now, when i try running my build,  the following message is shown:

```
> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (21.0.3) and runtime (26.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

**app\build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile



project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mapapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-beacons-manager')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

**settings.gradle:**

```
rootProject.name = 'mapapp'
include ':react-native-beacons-manager'
project(':react-native-beacons-manager').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
include ':app'
```

**MainApplication.java:**

```
package com.mapapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.mackentoch.beaconsandroid.BeaconsAndroidPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new BeaconsAndroidPackage(),
          new MapsPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

**android\build.gradle:**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

My Android version is 8.1.0.

Edit: When i applied the code from abhinandan sharma, the following message was shown:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\Users\Vex\PhpstormProjects\mapapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\mapapp\MainActivity.java:3: error
: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ReactActivity
  location: package com.facebook.react
C:\Users\Vex\PhpstormProjects\mapapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\mapapp\MainActivity.java:5: error
: cannot find symbol
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
                                  ^
  symbol: class ReactActivity
C:\Users\Vex\PhpstormProjects\mapapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\mapapp\MainApplication.java:5: er
ror: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: package com.facebook.react
C:\Users\Vex\PhpstormProjects\mapapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\mapapp\MainApplication.java:7: er
ror: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: package com.facebook.react
C:\Users\Vex\PhpstormProjects\mapapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\mapapp\MainApplication.java:17: e
rror: cannot find symbol
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
                                                            ^
  symbol: class ReactApplication
C:\Users\Vex\PhpstormProjects\mapapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\mapapp\MainApplication.java:19: e
rror: cannot find symbol
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
C:\Users\Vex\PhpstormProjects\mapapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\mapapp\MainApplication.java:41: e
rror: cannot find symbol
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
         ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
C:\Users\Vex\PhpstormProjects\mapapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\mapapp\MainActivity.java:11: erro
r: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\Vex\PhpstormProjects\mapapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\mapapp\MainApplication.java:19: e
rror: cannot find symbol
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
C:\Users\Vex\PhpstormProjects\mapapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\mapapp\MainApplication.java:40: e
rror: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
10 errors
```

Comment: Please add project level gradle??

Comment: Sorry, i added it now.

Comment: Where you write rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion targetSdkVersion and rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion ??

Comment: I don't know where they are written.

Comment: Please change this data it may solve your problem
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
minSdkVersion 15     
targetSdkVersion 28
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0''

Comment: I applied the changes, but the same error message is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in  your build.gradle file

> android -> build.gradle

```
  subprojects {
   project.configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
           if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                   && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
               details.useVersion "26.1.0"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Hope it Helps !

Comment: Now a different error came out. I will put it in the question.

Comment: you can add  issue here in comment also

Comment: have any ideas?